# ¿Como puedo hacer un "echo secuencial" (de imagenes) con PHP?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7

Es decir, que hasta que le muestre completamente la primera imagen al usuario, comience la segunda y así sucesivamente... y no todas juntas.

```html
while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
$imagenes = $filas['imagen'];
echo "<div><img src='imagenes/" . $imagenes . "'></div>";
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: Hay varias opciones, pero involucran Javascript: Una es usar [lazy load](https://carlosazaustre.es/lazy-loading-image), pero probablemente no es exactamente lo que quieres. Otra sería usar un [slider](https://www.deustoformacion.com/blog/programacion-diseno-web/tutorial-crear-slider-imagenes-con-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

La intención que comentas no es posible realizar con php, ya que el procesamiento de la respuesta con la colección de imágenes que imprime el while, se realiza en el servidor. Este ultimo solo entrega la respuesta al cliente por medio del navegador, y es en esta instancia donde se debe intervenir para que la carga sea secuencial en virtud de la experiencia del usuario. Para esto debes utilizar javascript para alterar el comportamiento de visualización de las imágenes.

Answer (score 0):

intenta utilizar un `foreach` en vez de un ciclo while y cierra la conexion al final de este, quedando de esta manera:

```html
foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($resultado) as $filas){
    $imagenes = $filas['imagen'];
    echo "<div><img src='imagenes/" . $imagenes . "'></div>";
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: No estoy seguro de que la función `mysqli_fetch_array()` sea iterable y, suponiendo que lo sea, no habrá diferencia en el resultado.